# The pagination on index.php doesn't work on a first page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, homepage

I have `index.php` with a pagination. The permalink settings is plain permalinks.

I have a correct pagination view when I open a page `/?paged=2` but if I open just `index.php` I have all posts without pagination. There is my `index.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

$args = array('post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' 
),'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => $paged);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args);


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>


<div class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-content">
        <div class="pg-block list">
        <?php
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;
        ?>
        </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <aside class="wrap-aside hid-xs">
            <div class="block-inner">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1');?>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-content">
        <?php
        //number of pages for pagination
        $total_pages =  $the_query->found_posts / $posts_per_page;

        if ($the_query->found_posts % $posts_per_page != 0) $total_pages++;
            $args_nav = array(
            'show_all'     => false, 
            'end_size'     => 2,     
            'mid_size'     => 2,     
            'prev_next'    => True,  
            'prev_text'    => '',    
            'next_text'    => '',    
            'total'        => $total_pages, 
            'add_args'     => False,
            'add_fragment' => '',     
            'screen_reader_text' =>  ' '
        );
            the_posts_pagination($args_nav);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Posts not found' ); ?></p>
<?php endif;

get_footer();?>
```

PS: I just edit my code like that but nothing was changed. The first page displays all posts without pagination

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-content">
        <div class="pg-block list">
        <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;
        ?>
        </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but two things. Do not change the  main query for a custom one on the home page. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. Also, `the_posts_pagination()` only works with the main query, it doesnot work with custom queries, except if you hack the main query

Comment: @PieterGoosen : I just edited my code like in P.S. but nothing was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding ignore sticky line inside array should solve the issue :)

```
$args = array(
       'post_type'      => 'post',
       'posts_per_page' => '6',
       'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,//this is the one :)
       'paged' => $paged,           
);
```

Comment: It is always worth adding a few words of explanation.

Comment: Added explanation while posting I didn't notice it got removed when I was editing

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines to your theme's function.php file and everything will get back to work:

```
add_filter(‘redirect_canonical’,’custom_disable_redirect_canonical’);

function custom_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {if (is_paged() && is_singular()) $redirect_url = false; return $redirect_url; }
```

Comment: Please clean up your code, it is unreadable as everything is in one lllloooonnngggg line